# Python: [Errno 2] No such file or directory, whilst it IS in the directory

Tags: python, list, csv, for-loop

I have the following code:

```
file_name = os.listdir("/Users/sophieramaekers/Downloads/CSV files") 

#remove the .csv part
file_name_noext = [f.replace('.csv', '') for f in file_name]
n_subjects = np.arange(0,len(file_name_noext))

#set path    
path = r'/Users/sophieramaekers/Downloads/CSV files'              
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv")) 

#read all files
df_from_each_file=[]
for f in n_subjects:
    df_sub = pd.read_csv(file_name[f])
    df_from_each_file.append(df_sub) #append each df_sub to the df_from_each_file list
```

But I keep getting the error That the files are not in the directory, whilst I'm 100% sure they are in the Downloads/CSV files directory. Anybody who can help me out?

I also tried it this way:

```
df_from_each_file = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_files] #read all files
```

But then it only reads the first two files and repeats those two files for the rest of the length of n_subjects. (so for example let's say the files are names a ab abc abcd abcde, then the df_from_each_file list looks like this: [a ab a ab a] instead of [a ab abc abcd abcde]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file_name` is the list of file names (duh) without the full path, so it looks for them in the working directory which (I assume) isn't `"/Users/sophieramaekers/Downloads/CSV files"`.

So try something like:

```
df_from_each_file=[]
for f in n_subjects:
    df_sub = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, file_name[f])) # adding the full path to the file
    df_from_each_file.append(df_sub)
```

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but I noticed it now only reads the first two files in de 'CSV files' map, and then repeats it for the rest of the loop (so df_from_each_file consists of a repetion of only the first two files in the map) Do you know what's going wrong here?